# How do I add custom fields in a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a view in Drupal 7, and used "Table" as format. How can I add my own fields to that table?

Answer (score 5):

One method is, in your view, click 'add' for fields, then filter by 'Global', and you will get 4 types of custom fields to add.

1. Global: Contextual Links
2. Global: Custom text
3. Global: Math expression
4. Global: View result counter

Another method is to make use of [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module.