# How to see field names of a view in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

How can I find the name of a certain field in my Drupal 7 view? For example I'm trying to find the event date field name in this view so that I can use it in my template file.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134870/can-we-add-new-column-to-a-view-programmatically or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162343/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-in-a-view or https://www.drupal.org/project/views_customfield

Answer (score 1):

You can hover over the field name on the view edit page and you will get the field machine name at the bottom left corner of your browser screen.

But what you should really do in my opinion is download and enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and add `dsm($fields);` in your template that will output all the fields available and their structure.